# Adding tooltip to mat datepicker in angular material2

Tags: angular-material

need to add mat tooltip for specific date in mat-datepicker.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-date-tooltip?file=app%2Fdatepicker-start-view-example.ts

I tried with this code but document.querySelectorAll(".endDate .mat-calendar-content[ng-reflect-ng-switch='month']"); is returning empty array

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-date-tooltip?file=app%2Fdatepicker-start-view-example.ts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a Material Tool Tip to a specifc date in Mat Date Picker Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49803938/how-to-add-a-material-tool-tip-to-a-specifc-date-in-mat-date-picker-angular)

Comment: @Roopa Did you ever get this figured out?